# Creating filter buttons that have an ID, that filter through elements with a rel of that same ID

Tags: jquery, html, filter

Here's my issue. I have these filtering buttons on my website, and each one has a name such as "UI, DEVELOPMENT, DATABASE, etc."

```
<ul class="tags_list">
    <li><a href="#" id="tag_ui">Ui</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="tag_database">Database</a></li>
    ...etc
</ul>
```

Then there are a bunch of elements in the page that have a REL that is equal to one of those IDs.

```
<ul class="story_list">
    <li rel="tag_ui"> *SOME CONTENT* </li>
    <li rel="tag_database"> *SOME CONTENT* </li>
    ...etc
</ul>
```

I also currently have some jquery that makes it so when you click on one of the "tags_list" filter button, it toggles any "story_list" element to hide or show depending on whether or not the "tags_list" button is selected or not.

```
$(".tags_list li a").on('click',function() {
    var relid = this.id;
    $(".story_list li[rel!='" + relid + "']").toggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Now this code works fine when you simply click on say "TAG_UI" button, then click again to deactivate it. But when you have TAG_UI activated, then you also click TAG_DATABASE, what happens is that "story_li" element BUT those two will show up, and those two will hide.

What I really need to happen is:

- When you initially click a filter button, only those associated
  elements will show, everything else will hide.
- When you click on another filter button, without deactivating the
  first one, only those two associated elements show, but everything
  else still hides.

So it is basically a filter. On initial page load, everything shows, but when you start clicking on the filter buttons, only the elements associated with those buttons show.

I know this is long-winded, so hopefully that all makes sense. Let me know if you need anything clarified.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's something missing here. Where's the `show` code? Your code only does a `.hide()`, yet you say it works to click again on the same element to toggle the related `story_list` elems.

Comment: `But when you have TAG_UI activated, then you also click TAG_DATABASE, what happens is that "story_li" element BUT those two will show up, and those two will hide.` can you please fix / clarify the last part of this sentence ?

Comment: Ahh crap. It should be toggle, actually. I messed that up. Sorry! I'll edit.

Comment: There isn't a `rel` attribute for `<li>` elements and for those element where it does exist, it doesn't take an id of another attribute. If you want to make up your own attributes for JS then use HTML 5's `data-*` attributes and no abuse something with a defined meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some classes while selecting and unselecting things will help you out a lot and let you style things.

Something like this should work:

```
var list = $(".story_list li");
$(".tags_list li a").on('click',function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var relid = this.id,
        that = $( this );
    if ( that.is(".selected") ) {
        that.removeClass( "selected" );
        list.filter("[rel='" + relid + "']").removeClass("selected").hide("fast");
    } else {
        list.filter(":not(.selected)[rel!='" + relid + "']")
            .removeClass("selected").hide("fast");
        list.filter("[rel='" + relid + "']")
            .addClass("selected").show("fast");
        that.addClass( "selected" );
    }
    // If nothing selected show everything
    if ( !list.filter(".selected").length ){
        list.show("fast");
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/TPjyG/

Comment: Holy moly! Judging by your jsfiddle, this looks to be exactly right. I'll test it out and let you know.

Comment: You, my friend, are a Genius! Works like a charm!

Comment: +1; The animation on that looks a little funky, but I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

So basically it seems to boil down to the associated element with the rel attribute matching the filter being clicked on toggling between hide and show.

This should satisfy the criteria of elements being shown when it is first clicked, and if a second type was clicked only those two types will be shown.

Clicking again on a filter will then hide the associated element;

```
$('.tags_list a').on('click', function() {
   $(".story_list li[rel='" + this.id + "']".toggle();
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Ubxuf/ to check if this is what you want ?

Comment: That is actually what I already had. See my edit. Sorry about that!

Comment: @jkilp your's has a `!=` I think it should be just equals `=` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that part. The code you posted works, but actually does the exact OPPOSITE of what I'm going for. With your code, all ".story_list" elements are shown initially, but if I click the filter button for "tag_ui", it hides all of the ".story_li" elements with REL="tag_ui". But what I want to happen is that EVERYTHING ELSE gets hidden, but that one stays visible.

Comment: Although, now that I think about it. Doing what you did is very easy, and makes sense. I could simply change how the active and inactive buttons look so that the user knows if they click on one of the filter buttons, it hides that one rather hide all the rest... hmmm.... If I can't find a good solution I may end up doing this.

Comment: ah, you missed my update two seconds later. that would be a matter of either hiding all `.story_list` elements at the beginning or doing what @Anthony Grist did with a global variable

Comment: The problem with what you have on jsfiddle is that I want ALL of the .story_list elements to show on page load. But from there you can toggle them on or off with the filter buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise a global variable that tracks whether or not a button has already been clicked, like so:

```
var buttonClicked = false;
```

Then in your `click` callback, hide every `<li>` element in the element with class `story_list` and track that a button has now been clicked, like so:

```
$(".tags_list li a").on('click',function() {
    var relid = this.id;
    if(!buttonClicked) {
        $(".story_list li").hide();
        buttonClicked = true;
    }
    $(".story_list li[rel='" + relid + "']").toggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Shoot, I didn't notice this answer at first. Yours works very well. But I think I'll need to add an "ALL" filter button to show everything. If I do that, this will work out perfect I think. I'll try this out then come back with an update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem the deisgn is that you are trying to handle more than one type of state transition with the same logic.  You have different behavior depending on the *set* of buttons that are selected:

- If all are unselected, the filter is deactivated and all items are shown
- If one or more are selected, then the filter is activated and only those items are shown

One way to solve this would be to check for both states, and do the appropriate transition for each:

```
on click:
  figure out the new state for the currently clicked button

  if enabling this button:
    check the previous state for all buttons

    if all buttons were unselected:
      hide all but the currently selected choice
      exit function

    show the filtered items
    exit function

  else (disabling this button):
    check the new state for all buttons

    if all buttons will now be unselected:
      show all but the previously selected choice
      exit function

    hide the filtered items
    exit function
```

You could use [the jQuery `data` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) or the `addClass` and `removeClass` methods to store the current "isSelected" state on the button itself.